# Python install mpi4py.MPI

Tags: python, c, mpi

I am trying to install [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html) as described in the [guide](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html). When I do

```
python setup.py build --mpicc=/usr/bin/mpicc
```

(or even without last argument), I get following error:

```
building 'mpi4py.MPI' extension
/usr/bin/mpicc -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/MPI.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/src/MPI.o
In file included from src/MPI.c:3:0:
src/mpi4py.MPI.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pyconfig.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you need to install `python-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

using pip:

```
sudo apt-get install pip
sudo pip install mpi4py
```

you can install it using `apt-get` directly:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mpi4py
```

Comment: Yes, that helped. But now I get another error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: compiling from source, you need to install all dependencies , better to use pip.

Comment: Last comamnd helped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bob anytime , enjoy Python :)